# Trouble with integral and use of Hölder's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm working on a proof showing an operator is compact. More specifically I arrive at an integral of the form:

$$\left|\int_{I}k(x)f(x)\ dx\right|^2$$

I proceeded to write this as

$$\left|\int_{I}k(x)f(x)\ dx\right|^2=\left|\int_{I}k(x)f(x)\ dx\right|\ \left|\int_{I}k(x)f(x)\ dx\right|$$

where I would use Hölder's inequality on each of the above integrals

$$\left|\int_{I}k(x)f(x)\ dx\right|\leq \int_{I}|k(x)f(x)|\ dx\leq\left(\int_{I}|k(x)|^2\ dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{I}|f(x)|^2\ dx\right)^{1/2}$$

This leads me to

$$\left|\int_{I}k(x)f(x)\ dx\right|^2\leq\left(\int_{I}|k(x)|^2\ dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{I}|f(x)|^2\ dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{I}|k(x)|^2\ dx\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{I}|f(x)|^2\ dx\right)^{1/2}$$

Does it then follow that

$$\left|\int_{I}k(x)f(x)\ dx\right|^2\leq \int_{I}|k(x)|^2\ dx\int_{I}|f(x)|^2\ dx$$

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why would the last line not follow from the line before? After all, you have $$\mathbb{I} < a^{1/2} b^{1/2} a^{1/2} b^{1/2} = ab$$

Comment: You've made it more complicated than it needs to be,
$ |\int kf | \le \|k\|_{L^2} \|f\|_{L^2}$ is just Cauchy-Schwarz / Holders. Then square both sides to obtain $|\int kf |^2 \le \|k\|^2_{L^2} \|f\|^2_{L^2}$

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I don't know why, but for some reason I started to doubt whether that also worked for integrals... I am two days away from defending my thesis and I found a mistake in a proof so that has stressed me out a bit so I think that's why. But now the proof is correct so now I can relax a bit more.